# PHP - how can i make from array to comma separate for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

PHP i am getting this:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(1) 
   { 
     ["username"]=> string(7) "9994344" 
   } 
  [1]=> array(1)
   {
     ["username"]=> string(7) "9994345" 
   } 
 }
```

How to make that into comma separate list

ex. `SELECT *from table1 WHERE column IN ("9994344","9994345")`

Comment: foreach loop but its slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$in_list = implode(',', array_map(function($x) {
    return '"' . $x['username'] . '"';
}, $array));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column IN ($in_list)";
```

Comment: I like the use of array_map();

Answer (score 1):

```
$ids=array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $ids[]=$row["UserID"]; 
} 
echo implode(", ", $ids);
```

Comment: You're missing the quotes around the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$arr_username = array();
foreach($arr as $arr_value)
{
    $arr_username[] = '"'.$arr_value['username'].'"';
}

$in = implode(",", $arr_username);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column IN ($in)";
```

Comment: You're missing the quotes around the usernames.

Comment: @Barmar i am updating the answer. whereas it can be work because username is a number. what you thing ?

Comment: Now it's essentially the same as my answer, except I use `array_map` instead of a loop.